# is there a way to prevent a form from submitting if I click "cancel" from the js confirm script that went before it?

Tags: javascript, php

I used the modal class in bootstrap, thru POST action to delete a record from the table, but it didn't have any confirmation to it so i tried using this confirm javascript.

The confirm works. The problem now is, even if I select "cancel" from the js confirm dialog box, it still deletes or routes to the delete.php file (which deletes the record) :o

Question: is there a way to prevent the form from submitting if I click "cancel" from the js confirm script? Thanks!

```
<!-- script and modal FROM THE HTML page users.php -->

<script>
function iconfirm() {
      var r = confirm("Do you really want to delete this user? Press ok to confirm.");
      if (r==true)
        {
        window.location="postDeleteUser.php";
    return true;
    }
       else
    {
    alert("You pressed Cancel!");
    window.location="users.php"
    }
 }
</script>

<div id="modDeleteUser" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modAddUser">
  <div class="modal-dialog bs-example-modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 id="modAddUser">Delete User</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="" action="postDeleteUser.php" method="post">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputID">Input the User ID of the user you are deleting:</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="input-small" id="inputID" placeholder="- ID No. -" name="txtuserid">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--<button type="submit">OK</button>-->
          <button onclick="iconfirm()" type="submit">OK</button>
          <!--======================-->

        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- FROM THE HTML page end -->




//=================== Delete.php start =========== //


<?php
$db_name="homeis";
$tbl_name="users";
$user_id=$_POST["txtuserid"];

include ("connect.php");
$deleteQuery= "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$user_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$deleteQuery);

if ($db->query($deleteQuery) === true) {
  echo "<script>alert('Data deleted!');window.location.href='users.php'</script>";
  }
else {
  echo "<script>alert('Unable to delete. Please try again.');window.location.href='users.php'</script>" . $conn->error;
  }

$db->close();

?>

//=================== Delete.php end =========== //
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if a user doesn't have JS enabled (I being one of them who only load JS from trusted sites, or that I know what's being loaded on my machine), will render your method useless. You should add a serverside method also, because when your code loads, it will want to load that `postDeleteUser.php` file.

Comment: Your delete function is also open to SQL injections. Look into prepared statements.

Comment: thanks, guys. i'll have these in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return false if you don't want the thing submitted..

add "return" here

```
<button onclick="return iconfirm()" type="submit">OK</button>
```

Then return something in the function. if you return true it will submit. if you return false, your computer might explode or something idk try it.

```
function iconfirm() {
      var r = confirm("Do you really want to delete this user? Press ok to confirm.");
      if (r==true)
        {
        window.location="postDeleteUser.php";
    return true;
    }
       else
    {
    alert("You pressed Cancel!");
    window.location="users.php"
    // return false here
    return false;
    }
 }
```

However, it might be easier to just..

```
<button onclick="return confirm('are you sure about whatever it is youre doing?')" type="submit">OK</button>
```